# Checking strings held in a list against those being read in from another device

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a list filed with data which I have already set up like so:

```
public List<string> stringValues = new List<string>();


void Start() 
{   
    stringValues.Add( "D5B51D14-9ED8-1530-5455-CFF2C4B86151");
    stringValues.Add( "335B8649-AB22-E146-05A0-E9A4F3813A1F");
    stringValues.Add( "28797BB5-9020-C0B5-F0CE-72AB7F1830E2");
    stringValues.Add( "CD377141-422D-E8B0-B845-A0AF408E565A");
    stringValues.Add( "DEEE65FB-FF1F-A6A9-4C3C-5784F41B0D39");
    stringValues.Add( "70489FFA-6C88-A40D-C615-FD1EDEBD7643");

}
```

I also have a method which reads in data being sent in from a device and displays it on the screen. I've had to cut a chop bits off of the string to make sure I only get the data I want, to appear on the screen.

This is what the method looks like:

```
private void AppendString(string message) 
{
    int startIndex = 38;
    int endIndex = 36;
    message = message.Substring(startIndex,endIndex);
    messageCount = "length is " + message.Length.ToString();
    outputContent.text += "\n" + message;
}
```

The thing is, the data getting sent into my program is something I have no idea about. It could contain anything. What I'm needing my program to do is check the portion of the string I need and compare the value it finds against those in my list. Then, should the list contain the same data, do something.

How can I go about comparing my list against data that is dynamically getting passed into it with my code above?

*edit*

I'll explain the appendMessage function a bit more and why it is like that:

the devices Im reading in send out data in the following way:

```
<CBPeripheral: 0xda4bab0 identifier = D5B51D14-9ED8-1530-5455-CFF2C4B86151, Name = "estimote", state = connecting>
```

Most of that is fine, but the only part I'm caring about is the long number held in the identifier portion of the line. In my program when I run the app, instead of displaying that entire line, the only part it puts out is that number there. Nothing else.

So, having chopped up that line, I'm storing in a UILabel (unity gui string) called `outputContent` and I'm accessing the data held in it when by calling `outputContent.text`

Which, when combined with the sample answer given below, my list check looks like this:

```
if(stringValues.Contains(outputContent.text))
{
    Instantiate(estimote6Model, new Vector3(2.5f,0.7f,0), Quaternion.identity);
    uuidString = "got an estimote 6";
}
```

However, whilst the string on display is the part of the line I want, nothing happens and I'm still trying to work out why.

Comment: Start index can't be greater than end index. Are you trying to compare the last 4 characters?

Comment: No, the whole string I get is actually: <CBPeripheral: 0xdc277c0 identifier = D5B51D14-9ED8-1530-5455-CFF2C4B86151, Name = "rawr", state = connecting> what I want is check only the identifier number which in the above case is D5B5 etc which starts at 38. Then I want it to only check the length of that number which is 36 characters long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search if the list with the method [.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So something like this:

```
if (stringValues.Contains(message))
{
   // do something
}
```

You can add this snipped at the end of your `AppendString()` method, because there, the variable `message` should hold the id's, which could be part of the `stringValues` list, right?

If you don't want to check for this within the `AppendString()` method, you must store your id's from the device in a separate list:

```
public List<string> deviceValues = new List<string>();

private void AppendString(string message) 
{
    int startIndex = 38;
    int endIndex = 36;
    message = message.Substring(startIndex,endIndex);
    messageCount = "length is " + message.Length.ToString();
    outputContent.text += "\n" + message;

    deviceValues.Add(message); // add here the input from the device
}
```

Then you can check if `stringValues` contains any of the values from `deviceValues` with:

```
if (stringValues.Any(x => deviceValues.Contains(x)))
{
   // do something
}
```

Comment: In `outputContent.text` you store `"\n" + message`. This means, that there is a "\n" AND the message you search for, and this does not match. Where should this `if` be in your code? If this should be within the method `AppendString()`, you should use `message` instead of `outputContent.text`. If not, you should add the value of `message` in a separate list. But what you can't do is checking for the value in `outputContext.text` as long as there is a `\n` in it.